# Receiving error while submitting forms in HTML

Tags: html, forms, input, hyperlink, google-search

I am working on a clone of Google's search page. I want the page to show search results in Google when the user uses it. But instead of taking the user to a search result page, the program is instead just putting the link after my page's link. I think I must have messed some somewhere in the code but can't figure out where. I'm just starting to learn HTML. Please help me through this. Thanks!

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N02b.png)

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Search</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="bar-right">
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="image.html">Image Search</a>
          <a href="advanced.html">Advanced Search</a>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="profile-trigger">
          <img src="images/profile.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="www.google.com/search" id="search">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
          <a href="" class="search-logo">
            <img src="images/google-logo.png">
          </a>
          <div class="search-bar">
            <div class="search-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="q">
          </div>
          <div class="search-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Search"></a>
            <a href="">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<form action="www.google.com/search" id="search">`, the action links to a place within your directory. To link to outside URLs, you need to use the http prefix.

`<form action="https://www.google.com/search" id="search">` fixes the issue.